# Count the number of customers on a specific status per month\year?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

| ID | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-10-01 | Silver |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | Gold |
| 3 | 2020-11-01 | Bronze |
| 1 | 2020-12-01 | Bronze |
| 1 | 2021-03-01 | Platinum |
| 2 | 2020-10-01 | Bronze |
| 3 | 2021-04-01 | Diamond |
| 2 | 2021-04-01 | Bronze |
| 1 | 2020-04-01 | Gold |

I need to count the number of customers per status per month, the thing is that the table only shows the entry when the status changed, but I would need to also account for the status for that particular customer on the months prior or after that.
For example, ID 1 was Gold before(we can assume because it was the first entry) and on 04\2020, and remained gold until 10\2020 when status changed to Silver, then Silver until 12\2020 when it changed to Bronze and so forth...
I would have to account for each customer for those months between the status changes that shows on the table, and I do not know how to do that.

I came up with this query, but it only accounts for the months where there was a status change, basically only the entries that shows on the table:

```
SELECT FORMAT(Date, 'yyyy-MM') AS Month_Year, Status, COUNT(ID) AS Count_Status
FROM Table1
GROUP BY FORMAT(Date , 'yyyy-MM'), Status
```

My output should be like:

| Month_Year | Status | Count_Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020\04 | Bronze | 11111 |
| 2020\04 | Silver... | 22222 |
| 2020\05 | Bronze | 11111 |
| 2020\05 | Silver... | 22222 |
| 2020\05 | Diamond | 33333 |

And so forth...

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

I also have another table that contains two columns, ID and Registration Date for each customer. How would be my approach to basically get the same output as above but this time account for only customer that registered on that particular month?

Thank you!

Comment: In fact your current query looks correct.  What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: It doesn't account for the values that do not show up in the table. For example, I cannot think of a solution to also count values that do not show in the table. For example, for customer ID 1, is only accounting for status that show in the table, but is not accounting for the months in between status changes, for example, if in January 2020 he was gold, and on march2020 he turned silver, is not accounting for February 2020 where he was still gold, because this entry isn't in the table.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  _They are certainly not the same thing_.

Comment: For next part of question ``I also have another table`` show test data and desirable output.

Comment: I'm using Sql Server

Comment: For the next part of your question, please ask a new question. Each SO question should contain a single question, not multiple,

Answer (score 0):

See example.
First we create calendar table - all month between min and max dates in table, or other date interval.
Then, expand status changes (status,from_date)->(status,from_date,to_date=next_date=next from_date).
Then JOIN Calendar table and expanded status changes table  and get status for every Id for every possible months.

```
with recursive dates as(  -- calendar table
  select min(date) yy_mm_1,max(date)edt from test
  union all
  select 
--    date_add(yy_mm_1,interval 1 month) yy_mm_1  -- mySql
    dateadd(1,month,yy_mm_1) yy_mm_1            -- SQL Server
    ,edt 
  from dates
  where 
   --  date_add(yy_mm_1,interval 1 month)<=edt
     dateadd(1,month,yy_mm_1)<=edt

)
,status_changes as( -- status changes from date to next date
select * 
  ,lead(date)over(partition by id order by date) next_date
from test
)
,all_status as( -- JOIN Calendar and status_changes
select d.yy_mm_1,t1.* 
from dates d
left join status_changes t1
 on t1.date<=d.yy_mm_1 and (d.yy_mm_1<t1.next_date or t1.next_date is null)
)

-- group by year_month and status
select yy_mm_1,status,count(*) status_count
  -- ,group_concat(id order by id separator ',') ids -- MySql
  ,string_agg(id,',') within group(order by id)ids    -- SQL Server
from all_status
group by yy_mm_1,status
order by yy_mm_1
```

For your test data

```
create table test (ID int,Date date,Status varchar(10));
insert into test values
 (1,'2020-10-01','Silver')
,(2,'2021-01-01','Gold') 
,(3,'2020-11-01','Bronze') 
,(1,'2020-12-01','Bronze') 
,(1,'2021-03-01','Platinum') 
,(2,'2020-10-01','Bronze') 
,(3,'2021-04-01','Diamond') 
,(2,'2021-04-01','Bronze') 
,(1,'2020-04-01','Gold')
;
```

result is

| yy_mm_1 | Status | status_count | ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-04-01 | Gold | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-05-01 | Gold | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-06-01 | Gold | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-07-01 | Gold | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-08-01 | Gold | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-09-01 | Gold | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-10-01 | Bronze | 1 | 2 |
| 2020-10-01 | Silver | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-11-01 | Bronze | 2 | 2,3 |
| 2020-11-01 | Silver | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-12-01 | Bronze | 3 | 1,2,3 |
| 2021-01-01 | Bronze | 2 | 1,3 |
| 2021-01-01 | Gold | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-02-01 | Bronze | 2 | 1,3 |
| 2021-02-01 | Gold | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-03-01 | Bronze | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-03-01 | Gold | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-03-01 | Platinum | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-04-01 | Bronze | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-04-01 | Diamond | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-04-01 | Platinum | 1 | 1 |

For the selected report interval, you can modify the query as follows (MySql syntax)

```
with recursive dates as(
  select cast('2020-10-01' as date) yy_mm_1,cast('2021-02-01' as date)edt 
  union all
  select date_add(yy_mm_1,interval 1 month),edt from dates
  where date_add(yy_mm_1,interval 1 month)<=edt
)
,status_changes as(
select * 
from(
  select * 
     ,lead(date)over(partition by id order by date) next_date
  from test
  where date<=cast('2021-02-01' as date)
  )t
where next_date>=cast('2020-10-01' as date) or next_date is null
)
,all_status as(
select d.yy_mm_1,t1.* 
from dates d
left join status_changes t1
 on t1.date<=d.yy_mm_1 and (d.yy_mm_1<t1.next_date or t1.next_date is null)
)
select yy_mm_1,status,count(*) status_count
  ,group_concat(id order by id separator ',') ids
from all_status
group by yy_mm_1,status
order by yy_mm_1
```

There result is

| yy_mm_1 | Status | status_count | ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-01 | Bronze | 1 | 2 |
| 2020-10-01 | Silver | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-11-01 | Bronze | 2 | 2,3 |
| 2020-11-01 | Silver | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-12-01 | Bronze | 3 | 1,2,3 |
| 2021-01-01 | Bronze | 2 | 1,3 |
| 2021-01-01 | Gold | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-02-01 | Bronze | 2 | 1,3 |
| 2021-02-01 | Gold | 1 | 2 |

Comment: It all makes sense now. Thank you very much.